# Retrieve access token from serverside code

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am new to developing against Facebook.  I need to be able to post to other people's walls from my website, which is c#.NET and asp.net.  I've already registered a facebook app to do this.

When I press a button on my website, I want to share content to a list of my own users that have provided me with their facebook URLs.  They will have granted the FB app permission to their wall.

There's not a lot of information on how to do this.  I need to:

1. Retrieve a new accesstoken, server side, using Facebook SDK.
2. Given a facebook url, get a user's profile
3. Share a link to their wall.

Comment: this post can help: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

i used php and javascript to connect FB SDK. i don't know it can implement to c#

1. you can get accessToken by FB.getLoginStatus
   developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
2. you can get some permission for grant what you want by "scope" parameter (look about Graph API)
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/
3. share some text to wall(feed) see "Publishing" at Graph API
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/

i hope it help you. 
sorry for my English skill.

Answer (score 0):

first download the nuget package or dll from https://github.com/barans/FacebookCsharpSdk

fill the appid and secret from www.facebook.com/developers

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object>();
config.Add("appId", "3955.......");
config.Add("secret", "4c1d...............");
config.Add("fileUpload", true); //optional
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(config);
```

this code retrieves the access token
    client.getAccessToken();

this code retrieves the current user information which is publicly available. you can replace me with a facebook id like "999999"

```
client.api("/me", "GET", null));
```

facebook does not allow server side wall posting to an arbitrary user. you can only post to the current user's wall and first you should ask publish_stream permission. after getting that this piece of code makes a wall post

```
request.Method = FacebookApiMethodType.POST;
request.Path = "/me/feed";
request.Params = new NameValueCollection();
request.Params.Add("link", "www.arcademonk.com");
request.Params.Add("message", "C# SDK Batch Request Messsage");
```

you can find the all documentation on github page. hope it helps.